# Error en creación de Stored Procedure Oracle 12c

Tags: plsql, oracle-12c

ante todo les aclaro que es mi primera Stored Procedure en Oracle, ya que vengo de escribirlas en Informix durante 20 años.

El código de la SP es el siguiente:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE xxLocalidadPorCategoria
IS

crearTempFacturado  VARCHAR2(1000);
crearResumen        VARCHAR2(1000);
llenarTempFacturado VARCHAR2(1000);
llenarResumen       VARCHAR2(1000);

CURSOR CR IS 
     SELECT IdLocalidad, Localidad, Unid_CFijo, Imp_CFijo, Unid_Consumo, Imp_Consumo, Unid_CFijoGC, 
Imp_CFijoGC, Unid_ConsumoGC, Imp_ConsumoGC, Unid_Demanda, Imp_Demanda, Unid_Bonificacion, 
Imp_Bonificacion,
Unid_Coseno, Imp_Coseno, Unid_Cargos, Imp_Cargos, Unid_Ajustes, Imp_Ajustes, Unid_Bonif_Exc, 
Imp_Bonif_Exc, Unid_Reajustes, Imp_Reajustes, Unid_COIE, Imp_COIE, Unid_COIE_DEM, Imp_COIE_DEM
        FROM xxResumen
            ORDER BY IdLocalidad
            FOR UPDATE NOWAIT;

BEGIN

crearTempFacturado := 
    'CREATE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE xxTemp_Facturado
        (IdSuministro   NUMBER(10),
        IdSum_Ene   NUMBER(10),
        NroSum      NUMBER(14),
        IdCategoria VARCHAR2(5),
        Descripcion VARCHAR2(50),
        Anio        NUMBER(10),
        NroPer      NUMBER(10),
        IdConcepto  NUMBER(10),
        IdSubConcepto   NUMBER(10),
        Unidades    NUMBER(14,2),
        Importe     NUMBER(14,2),
        IdLocalidad NUMBER(10),
        Localidad   VARCHAR2(50),
        NroSocio    NUMBER(10),
        IdCbteUnif  NUMBER(10),
        )
        ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS;';

crearResumen :=
    'CREATE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE xxResumen
        (IdCategoria    VARCHAR(5),
        Descripcion VARCHAR2(50),
        IdLocalidad NUMBER(10),
        Localidad   VARCHAR(50),
        Unid_CFijo  NUMBER(10),
        Imp_CFijo   NUMBER(14,2),
        Unid_Consumo    NUMBER(14,2),
        Imp_Consumo NUMBER(14,2),
        Unid_CFijoGC    NUMBER(10),
        Imp_CFijoGC NUMBER(14,2),
        Unid_ConsumoGC  NUMBER(14,2),
        Imp_ConsumoGC   NUMBER(14,2),
        Unid_Demanda    NUMBER(14,2),
        Imp_Demanda NUMBER(14,2),
        Unid_Bonificacion   NUMBER(10),
        Imp_Bonificacion    NUMBER(14,2),
        Unid_Coseno NUMBER(10),
        Imp_Coseno  NUMBER(14,2),
        Unid_Cargos NUMBER(10),
        Imp_Cargos  NUMBER(14,2),
        Unid_Ajustes    NUMBER(10),
        Imp_Ajustes NUMBER(14,2),
        Unid_Bonif_Exc  NUMBER(10),
        Imp_Bonif_Exc   NUMBER(14,2),
        Unid_Reajustes  NUMBER(10),
        Imp_Reajustes   NUMBER(14,2),
        Unid_COIE   NUMBER(10),
        Imp_COIE    NUMBER(14,2),
        Unid_COIE_DEM   NUMBER(10),
        Imp_COIE_DEM    NUMBER(14,2),
        )
        ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS;';
    
 llenarTempFacturado :=
     'INSERT INTO xxTemp_Facturado
         SELECT cc.IdSuministro, cc.IdSuministro IdSum_Ene, cc.NroSum, cc.IdCategoria, 
 cat.Descripcion Categoria, cc.Anio, cc.NroPer, ccp.IdConcepto, ccp.IdSubConcepto, ROUND( 
ccp.Unidades, 2 ) Unidades, ccp.Importe, f.IdLocalidad, l.Descripcion, cc.NroSocio, cc.IdCbte
            FROM Cbtes_Coop cc, Cbtes_Cptos ccp, Suministros s, SubFincas sf, Fincas f, Categorias 
cat, Localidades l -----, OUTER( Sim_Cbtes sc, OUTER( Categorias cat, Suministros s, Localidades l ))
            WHERE cc.Anio = 2019
            AND cc.NroPer = 10
            AND cc.Estado != "X"
            AND cc.IdTipo_Srv = 1
            ----AND cc.IdSuministro = 1078      ----Agregada para control
            AND cc.IdEmpresa = ccp.IdEmpresa
            AND cc.IdSucursal = ccp.IdSucursal
            AND cc.Tipo_Cbte = ccp.Tipo_Cbte
            AND cc.Grupo_Cbte = ccp.Grupo_Cbte
            AND cc.Letra_Cbte = ccp.Letra_Cbte
            AND cc.NroCbte = ccp.NroCbte
            AND ccp.IdConcepto IN ( SELECT IdConcepto FROM Conceptos WHERE IdTipo_Srv = 1 )
            AND NOT EXISTS ( SELECT IdEmpresa
                                FROM Cbtes_Coop
                                WHERE IdCbte_Padre = cc.IdCbte
                                AND IdSucursal IN ( 4, 47, 48 )
                                AND Tipo_Cbte = "NC"
                                AND IdTipo_ModoFac > 0
                                AND Estado != "X"
                                AND ABS( Totalimp ) = ABS( cc.Totalimp ))
            AND cc.IdSuministro = s.IdSuministro
            AND s.IdSubFinca = sf.IdSubFinca
            AND sf.IdFinca = f.IdFinca
            AND f.IdLocalidad = l.IdLocalidad
            AND cc.IdTipo_Srv = cat.IdTipo_Srv
            AND cc.IdCategoria = cat.IdCategoria;';

llenarResumen :=
    'INSERT INTO xxResumen
        SELECT IdCategoria, Descripcion, IdLocalidad, Localidad, SUM( CASE WHEN xx.IdConcepto = 5 
THEN 1 END ) Cargo_Fijo, SUM( CASE WHEN xx.IdConcepto = 5 THEN xx.Importe END ) Importe_C_Fijo, SUM( 
CASE WHEN xx.IdConcepto = 10 THEN ROUND( xx.Unidades, 2 ) END ) kWh, SUM( CASE WHEN xx.IdConcepto = 
        10 THEN xx.Importe END ) Importe_Consumo, SUM( CASE WHEN xx.IdConcepto IN( 35, 38 ) THEN 1 
END) Cargo_Fijo_GC, SUM( CASE WHEN xx.IdConcepto IN( 35, 38 ) THEN xx.Importe END ) Imp_C_Fijo_GC, 
SUM( CASE WHEN xx.IdConcepto IN( 30, 31, 32 ) THEN ROUND( xx.Unidades, 2 ) END ) Energia_GC,  SUM(  
        CASE WHEN xx.IdConcepto IN( 30, 31, 32 ) THEN xx.Importe END ) Importe_GC, SUM( CASE WHEN 
xx.IdConcepto IN( 40, 41 ) THEN ROUND( xx.Unidades, 2 ) END ) Unidades_Demanda, SUM( CASE WHEN 
xx.IdConcepto IN( 40, 41 ) THEN xx.Importe END ) Importe_Demanda, SUM( CASE WHEN xx.IdConcepto IN( 
101, 109 
        ) THEN 1 END ) Cant_BEN, SUM( CASE WHEN xx.IdConcepto IN( 101, 109 ) THEN xx.Importe END ) 
BEN, SUM( CASE WHEN xx.IdConcepto = 62 AND xx.Importe != 0 THEN 1 END ) Ajuste_Coseno, SUM( CASE WHEN 
xx.IdConcepto = 62 AND xx.Importe != 0 THEN xx.Importe END ) Imp_Ajuste_Coseno, SUM( CASE WHEN 
        xx.IdConcepto IN ( 25, 26, 27, 29, 291,292, 293, 294, 295 ) THEN 1 END ) Cant_Cargos_Ersep, 
SUM( CASE WHEN xx.IdConcepto IN ( 25, 26, 27, 29, 291,292, 293, 294, 295 ) THEN xx.Importe END ) 
Imp_Cargos_Ersep, SUM( CASE WHEN xx.IdConcepto IN ( 20, 21, 23, 24, 64, 100, 432, 433, 434 ) THEN 1 
END ) 
        Cant_Ajustes_Ersep, SUM( CASE WHEN xx.IdConcepto IN ( 20, 21, 23, 24, 64, 100, 432, 433, 434 
) THEN xx.Importe END ) Imp_Ajustes_Ersep, SUM( CASE WHEN xx.IdConcepto = 28 AND xx.IdSubConcepto = 1 
THEN 1 END ) Unid_Bonif_Exc, SUM( CASE WHEN xx.IdConcepto = 28 AND xx.IdSubConcepto = 1 THEN 
        xx.Importe END ) Imp_Bonif_Exc, SUM( CASE WHEN xx.IdConcepto IN( 438, 439 ) AND 
xx.IdSubConcepto = 0 THEN 1 END ) Unid_Reajustes, SUM( CASE WHEN xx.IdConcepto IN( 438, 439 ) AND 
xx.IdSubConcepto = 0 THEN xx.Importe END ) Imp_Reajustes, SUM( CASE WHEN xx.IdConcepto = 58 AND 
xx.IdSubConcepto = 
        0 THEN 1 END ) Unid_Coie, SUM( CASE WHEN xx.IdConcepto = 58 AND xx.IdSubConcepto = 0 THEN 
xx.Importe END ) Imp_Coie, SUM( CASE WHEN xx.IdConcepto = 296 AND xx.IdSubConcepto = 0 THEN 1 END ) 
Unid_Coie_Dem, SUM( CASE WHEN xx.IdConcepto = 296 AND xx.IdSubConcepto = 0 THEN xx.Importe END ) 
        Imp_Coie_Dem
            FROM xxTemp_Facturado xx
                GROUP BY IdCategoria,Descripcion,IdLocalidad,Localidad;';

    
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE crearTempFacturado;
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE crearResumen;
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE llenarTempFacturado;
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE llenarResumen;

    FOR cursorResumen IN CR LOOP

        dbms_output.put_line( cursorResumen.IdLocalidad);

    END LOOP;            

END xxLocalidadPorCategoria;
```

Cuando compilo, me arroja los siguientes errores:

LINE/COL  ERROR

---

10/6      PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
12/18     PL/SQL: ORA-00942: la tabla o vista no existe
126/9     PL/SQL: Statement ignored
126/31    PLS-00364: el uso de la variable 'CURSORRESUMEN' de índice de bucle no es válido

Comento lo que hice:

En un principio creé las tablas temporales con la notación de Informix (smallint, integer, varchar, decimal) y me aceptó la sintaxis.

Luego fui creando de a poco la SP, dejando para el último el cursor.

Mientras iba compilando, no arrojaba ningún error.

Hice un Truncate y Drop a las tablas temporales creadas manualmente, y comenzaron los errores.

Cambié a notación de Oracle la definición de las columnas de ambas tablas, y cuando las quiero crear en forma manual me sale el error:
Informe de error -
ORA-00904: : identificador no válido
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
*Cause:
*Action:
Y nada más, ni un enlace a la línea que está mal.

Lo del cursor no sé si está bien definido. Pero haciendo manualmente la creación de tablas temporales, la inserción de los datos y luego una consulta sobre la tabla xxResumen, veo que funciona todo.

El problema es en el ensamblaje de la SP.

Agradecería muchísimo a quien me pueda ayudar con esto.

Perdonen la extensión del post.

Answer (score 0):

1-Nunca va a compilar porque la tabla "xxResumen" NO existe al momento de la compilación.

2-¿porqué las tablas temporales se crean dentro del procedimiento?
No es una buena práctica y se compromete la seguridad de la base de datos.
Lo mejor es crearlas previamente.